# Where to specify DNS search options?

Tags: kali-linux, dns

If I use Network Manager that does not have DNS search options available (Kali) then what file should I use to define the search options? These don't seem to care /etc/resolv.conf & /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf & /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: Are you referring to DNS search suffixes?

Comment: Correct. Seems nobody can give clear answer where that should be defined. In my humble opinion *nix has dropped the ball on this one.

Comment: *"Seems nobody can give clear answer where that should be defined."* Don't jump to conclusions. It's only been a little over three hours since you posted this question.

Comment: @michael This is not the first place I asked. People keep telling me what I allready know and/or confusing the issue. Where does the Network Manager hide it's config? Or what files does it use to create the config?

Answer (score 1):

Search options go in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  There are various ways this gets built.  The command `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf` should show if the file is real, or a symbolic link.  The command  `man resolv.conf` should describe what you can put in `resolv.conf`.

The command `man -k resolv | grep conf` should give you a list of the available man pages related to configuring `resolv.conf` on your system.  `resolvconf` is a commonly used program to configure `resolv.conf`.  It can

Search lists can cause issues.  A long search list can slow down DNS resolution of incorrectly specified domain names.  Or it can return unexpected matches.  I've learned to keep my search list short and carefully controlled.

There are a few options:

- DHCP / Network Manager are likely using `resolvconf` to update `resolve.conf`.  In this case `/etc/resolv.conf` will be a symbolic link to the dynamically generated `resolv.conf` file.  You should be able to disable resolvconf by replacing `/etc/resolv.conf` with a real file.
- Add a `dns-search` specification to the `iface lo` stanza in `/etc/network/interfaces`.
- Disable or uninstall Network Manager, may be required if the other options don't work.  Will require an alternate configuration such as the following option.
- Configure your external interface, likely `eth0` using `/etc/network/interfaces`.  This should cause Network Manager to ignore the interface.  Add a staza like:

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
      dns-search example.com

You can also move IPv6 configuration as well.

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

More details can be found in the `man` pages, and the documentation files usually found in `/usr/share/doc/`.

Comment: Settings in /etc/resolv.conf have been tested and they work... for a while, until they are over written by the Network Manager. Questing is where can I define DNS search suffixes if not in the Network Manager?

Comment: @SamTzu See updates to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Basically my options seem to be to... either give up on DNS search prefixes or to give up on Network Manager. I wish I knew who to send the flowers to.

Comment: @SamTzu  If you set the search in /etc/network/interfaces on the loopback 'lo' interface, it should be used if DHCP does not provide a search list.

Comment: THANK YOU BILL!!! It took me over a year to find this info. I never thought about putting dns search prefix to 'loopback' interface. Seems kind of counter intuitive but it works.

Comment: Plaah. I talked too soon. It does not work.

Comment: It used to be that I was able to define the search domains in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail. Not anymore.

Comment: @SamTzu  Are you getting an empty search list from the DHCP server?  resolvconf has an order of preference for the data.  domain can be used if only one item is in the search list.   It is us

Comment: What DHCP server? I'm using both static IP's and DHCP servers (in plural.) I just want to have my search options always in order.

Comment: @SamTzu If everything is static use /etc/network/interfaces.  Network Manager is more suitable for systems which frequently connect to unknown networks.

Comment: That's why my original question... how to manage DNS search options with Network Manager (that has no search options. Kali Linux v.3)